# Angular and Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'IData' has no index signature

Tags: angular, typescript, indexing

I need to display some object properties based on the predefined keys in the array. Example (TypeScript):

```
const dataObject: IData = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const dataKeys: string[] = ['a', 'c'];

dataKeys.forEach((key: string): void => { console.log(dataObject[key]); })
```

So, the Angular code looks like:

Angular template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let key of dataKeys">
    {{ dataObject[key] }}
</ng-container>
```

Angular component:

```
type DataKeys = Array<keyof IData>;

public dataObject: IData = { a: 1, b: 1 };
public dataKeys: DataKeys = ['a', 'b'];
```

When compiling Angular's code I am keep getting following error:

> error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'IData' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?

I understand the concern, but however, in the component itself when I do:

```
this.dataKeys.forEach((column: keyof IData): void => {
  console.log(this.dataObject[column]);
});
```

then TypeScript doesn't raise any issue with that code.

Any hints how to resolve the above issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: share IData interface/type

Comment: @captain-yossarian What do you mean by "share" here?

Comment: I mean, I'm unable to reproduce the issue because of lack of IData type. If you provide it it will be much easier to answer your question

Comment: `interface IData { a: number; b: number; c: number; d?: IOtherInterface }`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
interface IData { a: number; b: number; c: number; }

const dataObject: IData = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

type DataKeys = Array<keyof IData>;
const dataKeys: DataKeys = ['a', 'c'];

dataKeys.forEach((key): void => { console.log(dataObject[key]); }) // ok
```

Comment: The workaround:

public getData(data: IData, key: keyof IData): any {
    return data[key];
  }

and then template is being compiled without issues. I don't like "any" here, just to be clear.

Comment: could you please share in any sandbox? I don't have configured angular project

Comment: Sure. I will prepare the sandbox.